# Sorting algorithm with run error

Tags: java, sorting

Hey i wanted to do some excercise in java, by reading a .txt files filled with numbers, and then creating one with the numbres from max to min.

In order to do that i made some classes. This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Texto {

    String fileName;

    public Texto(String nombreArchivo) {
        this.fileName = nombreArchivo;                  
    }

    public LinkedList storeArray() {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        int a=0;
        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
            String temp="";
            while (temp!=null) {
                list.add(buffer.readLine());
                temp=list.get(a).toString(); // line 25
                a++;                
            }
            list.remove(a);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return storeArray().size(); // line 41
    }

    public void orderFile() {
        try {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("archivoOrdenado.txt");
            BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(file);
            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(buffer);
            int array[] = new int[getLength()]; // line 52

            for (int i=0;i<getLength();i++) {
                array[i]=(Integer)storeArray().get(i);
            }

            int temp;

            for (int i=0;i<getLength();i++) {
                for (int j=1;i<getLength();j++) {
                    if (array[i]<array[j]) {
                        temp=array[i];
                        array[i]=array[j];
                        array[j]=temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i=0;i<getLength();i++) {
                print.println(array[i]);
            }
            print.close();
            buffer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

And in another class y call this methods like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Texto t = new Texto("numeros.txt");
        t.orderFile();
    }
}
```

The run error says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Texto.storeArray(Texto.java:25)
    at Texto.getLength(Texto.java:41)
    at Texto.orderFile(Texto.java:52)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

This is line 25 : `temp=list.get(a).toString();` 
41: `return storeArray().size();` 
52: `int array[] = new int[getLength()];`

Comment: What is the compiler error message?  Please post it.

Comment: So, and now we need to *guess* where that thing refuses to compile?

Comment: OK, sorry, i think i rush 2 post it. It says
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Texto.storeArray(Texto.java:25)
 at Texto.getLength(Texto.java:41)
 at Texto.orderFile(Texto.java:52)
 at Main.main(Main.java:6)

Comment: That's a runtime error, not a compile time error....

Comment: That's not a compiler error, that's a run time error

Comment: Thanks 4 that, so what is giving me that error, and why this isn't working

Comment: It'd also be helpful if you could show us what lines 25, 41, and 52 are in Texto.java

Comment: This is line 25 : temp=list.get(a).toString();
41: return storeArray().size();
52: int array[] = new int[getLength()];

Answer (score 2):

Follow the comments:

```
    String temp="";
    while (temp!=null)
    {
        list.add(buffer.readLine()); // buffer.readLine() will return null at EOF
                                     // but that isn't tested here
        temp=list.get(a).toString(); // so at EOF you .toString() null - NPE.
        a++;                
    }
```

Rewrite it into something like this

```
    String temp="";
    while (temp!=null) {
        temp=buffer.readLine();
        if (temp != null) {
            list.add(temp);
        }
    }
```

Then that `list.remove(a);` after the end of the loop can also be dropped, as it's just there to correct the fact that you ended with null.

EDIT: version with just 1 comparison, a bit more compact but maybe a bit less readable

```
    String temp="";
    while ((temp = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
         list.add(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, was thinking is something like that, just didn't liked the idea of 2 "temp!=null"

Now i have this error code
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
 at Texto.orderFile(Texto.java:56)
 at Main.main(Main.java:6)

Comment: Well that new error says exactly what's going on: with `array[i]=(Integer)storeArray().get(i);` you try to cast (casting != converting) a String to an Integer, and you can't do that.  Due to the increasing homework smell just a tip: have a look at [Integer's JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) there may be some method to parse an Int from a String :-)